# How to obtain packages in workbench in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Oh, well, the question is as stated. I want to obtain somehow list of created packages that are placed in the **workbench** directory of my laravel app.Is there a good Laravel-way to do that nicely? Thanks.

Comment: `ls workbench/myName` ?

Comment: Oh.., that way I can do. But I thought there is a more proper solution

Comment: artisan does not have such a command sadly (just checked php artisan), at least not that I know of. I would make a custom command using `directories()` using filesystem and call make it call `like php artisan workbench:list myName` though. I'll try to make one tomorrow.

For more info: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Filesystem.Filesystem.html#249-265

Comment: thx for the link. will study this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing the directory is the current only way of viewing a list of your workbench packages, but you can make it fancy:

Create an alias

```
alias bench="find workbench/ -maxdepth 2 -type d | egrep '/.*/' | cut -d '/' -f2,3"
```

Then you just have to type

```
bench
```

And you should see:

```
vendorNameA/packageNameA 
secondVendor/packageNameB
```

Comment: nice, would this work independant of environment(I mean win/linux/etc)?

Comment: This is platform dependent, I'd rather use `Illuminate\Filesystem` and make a custom `artisan` command.